# How to Create Events Calendar

Tags: events, calendar, the-events-calendar

How onthisday.com has been made?
I'd want to make something similar.

I guess I need to have a database with some events happened in a day (6 february 2021, 6 february 2020, 6 february 2019 ... 6 february 2014)
and then I want to show all the events happened on that day.

I have no idea on how to start and I'll appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: Yes, that sounds about right. You'd just have to decide how you're going to store the date against each event, e.g. as the post's date or in another property, and then change the homepage query to search for all events that match today's day and month. I suspect that's easiest done as a SQL query rather than the usual WP_Query arguments.

Comment: yeah, thanks for your comment.

but there are few more things, like:

If the price for a product was $100 on february 6, 2015 and today is $120, i'd like to show how much has been increased/decreased - in our case +20%

and I will want to set a price in any year on the same date (2015, 2016, 2021, etc)

i know it's a "custom" job. can you recommend someone?